# IBM Maximo Worker Insights - how do I configure it?

Tags: maximo, ibm-maximo-worker-insights

What are the steps to configure the IBM Maximo Worker Insights instance.

I'm trying to use the product's API and the dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

See [Getting Started with Maximo Worker Insights](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSQNYQ_bas/worker-insights/safer_workplace/worker_get_start_tasks.html).

1. Create the admin user
2. Define the organization hierarchy
3. Add additional users
4. Activate shields for users